# guardar resultado query builder en variable Laravel

Tags: laravel

estoy tratando de guardar el resultado de una consulta de query builder en una variable.

En mi controlador

```
$sql = DB::select("SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE id_autor = 4");

$articulo->autor = $sql;                     
$articulo->update();
```

pero al hacer dd($sql); me muestra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo hacer para que la variable $sql guarde UNICAMENTE el valor, por ejmplo $sql='15'. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hola buenas puedes hacer lo siguente, si lo que quieres es traer solo el valor de idProducto:

```
$sql = DB::table('articulos')->where('id_autor', 4)->value('idProducto');
```

puedes hacer dd($sql) y veras que te trae el valor.

Comment: Gracias @Sergio, intente hacerlo con un DB::select("SELECT idProducto FROM producto INNER JOIN....")->value('idProducto'); pero no FUNCIONA.

Comment: hola @Edu27 , te dejo la documentacion de como trabajar con Query Builder joins [aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins)